# Kubuntu 20.04 Display Errror

Tags: linux, display, kubuntu, resolution

I have a problem with my resolution.
System Kubuntu 20.04 64bit.
Graphics 1050Ti.
Display LS23EMDKU/EN.

Current Resolution 1920×1080.
I must set force dpi (96) font because I can't see anything.

My current effect:
[image]

In Windows 10 is much better. So probably is software error or wrong config.

Comment: Are you using Nvidia drivers? If so, what version?

Comment: NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0